# how to check alert is visible android

Tags: java, android, alert, android-alertdialog

how to check if my alert is already showing on screen ?

```
 AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

 alert.show();
```

I can maintain state by adding a flag in my code to set and reset, but if there is already a method that I can re use ?

Comment: Please be clear. Do you want to check if alert is currently being shown?

Comment: yes exactly @MysticMagic

Comment: `alert.isShowing()` method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no isShowing() method on the AlertDialog.Builder class. There is one on the Dialog class though.

[AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

[Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#isShowing%28%29)

An AlertDialog.Builder is used to create an AlertDialog. Once you have an instance of an AlertDialog, you can determine whether or not it is still showing by then calling isShowing() on it.

```
AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

if(!alertDialog.isShowing()){   
  //if its visibility is not showing then show here 
   alertDialog.show();       
 }else{
  //do something here... if already showing       
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can check it with isShowing(); method
it's documented in the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#isShowing()) too

But in your case you need to catch the AlertDialog that build by the AlertDialog.Builder first.
so your code should be like this

```
AlertDialog alertDialog;

function showDialog() {
    if(alertDialog == null) { 
        //Initial Creation will always show 
        //or you can just use create() if you don't want to show it at initial creation
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.show();
    else {
        if(alertDialog.isShowing()) {
             alertDialog.hide();
        } else {
             alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but I want to decide weather to show or not based on its visiblity, can I do it before invoking show() ?

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();

//to check if its being shown
if(!alertDialog.isShowing()){
    //do something
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

It will return `true` if currently that alert dialog is being shown. So in your case, check if it returns `false`, and then show it.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use isShowing method of dialog or you can maintain flag like when you create alert dialog flag is 0 and after showing make it 1.